# Showing line number enabled description of C++ code

Tags: latex

```
1 int main(){

2 long count = 0;
3 long rd = 0;

4 return 0;
5 }
```

Above is the C++ code and we need to refer this line number using a `\ref`.
Suppose in my LaTeX article I have to do code explanation using line numbers.
For example, line number 1 is all about `int main` for the above C++ code. Similarly, line number 2 is all about variable declaration.

```
1 int main(){

2 long count = 0;/*@\label{stat-3}*/
3 long rd = 0;/*@\label{stat-4}*/

4 return 0;
5 }
```

Above is the C++ code and we need to refer to this line number using `\ref`.
Suppose in my LaTeX article I have to do code explanation using line number like `\ref{stat-3}`. But for me it is not working.

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668902/showing-line-number-enabled-description-of-c-code

Comment: Please include links to each other in **all** versions of your question. Cross-posting like this risks wasting the time of users trying to help you because they might not see if your question already has an answer on one of the other sites and it will waste the time of future users with the same problem because they might not find solutions which exist somewhere else.